# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_federated.python.research'

Tags: python, ubuntu, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

The following error occurred while running "https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/gans/experiments/emnist/run_experiments.py" (I am attempting to regenerate the results of the paper):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_federated.python.research'
```

1. Here is the full list of my anaconda environment information:[conda environment information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZad1.png)
2. and I am using Pycharm in Ubuntu 16.04:[IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDOf8.png)
3. Last but not least, I have tried to execute the code in the terminal but the error continued to exist, so I'm afraid that the problem is not concerned with the Pycharm IDE.[the problem is not concerned with IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCUCZ.png)

It will be appreciated if you could give me some suggestions.

Comment: How and from what folder did you run the program? Did you [run all the installation steps?](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/install.md)

Comment: Thank you for your response, and I have found  the URL above which describes my detail configuration is not accessible. Sorry for the inconvenience. As a matter of fact, I have also opened an issue in the corresponding GitHub repository:https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues/814. Hope you can find my execution details there.

Answer (score 2):

This research project follows the TensorFlow Federated practice of using the [bazel](https://bazel.build) build system. The python scripts cannot be run directly.

After installing bazel, try the following commandline:

```sh
$ bazel run \
tensorflow_federated/python/research/gans/experiments/emnist:run_experiments
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am surprised to receive your reply in Stack Overflow. With your help, I have made some progresses in addressing this issue, and the status of the issue is updated in GitHub(https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues/814). Could you please go to that page and give me some more suggestions?